# Query : problem in where section

Tags: sql, where-clause

I need to write a query like this :

```
SELECT S , D1 , D2 , (D1+D2) as D_Sum , ( (D1+D2) / 
                 (X-(
                 SELECT SUM(T1+T2) 
                 FROM TBL1 
                 WHERE FCode=81 AND DCode=1 AND S<S
                 )) AS SSS 
FROM TBL1 
WHERE Salon=1 AND FCode=81 AND DCode=1
```

I have problem with `S<S` in where section in sub query . `S<S` likes FALSE and doesn't works .

First S are all of s in all of records in the table and second S is stored in each record .

`S<S` : I need select all records that their s is smaller than the s is stored in the record that now processed .

Comment: Can you correct the text? It's very difficult to understand the text :)

Comment: this code has no error . but only i changed the fields name because you cant know my language .

Comment: All I can say is that `S<S` is always false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a name to the tables:

```
SELECT S , D1 , D1 , (D1+D2) as D_Sum , ( (D1+D2) / 
                 (X-(
                 SELECT SUM(innerTBL.T1+innerTBL.T2) 
                 FROM TBL1 innerTBL 
                 WHERE innerTBL.FCode=81 AND innerTBL.DCode=1 AND outerTBL.S<innerTBL.S
                 )) AS SSS 
FROM TBL1 outerTBL
WHERE Salon=1 AND FCode=81 AND DCode=1
```

Note: I should use the work "alias" instead of "name".

Comment: still - they need an alias since you are referencing twice

Comment: You can give it a name in the query (innerTBL and outerTBL in the example). Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see the problem.

Comment: @Arash, since the `TBL1` is being used multiple times, you need to reference a specific instance of it.  So, the comparison isn't between the same column in a single table, but rather two columns with the same name in two joined tables.

Comment: @DavidEG Count the number of parenthesis :)